# How to : rename method return type (C#, Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, refactoring

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void SaveLog(Log log);
    Log ReadLog();     //To be : List<Log> ReadLog();
    Log ReadLastLog();
}
```

`ReadLog` method is used in many classes.
I want to change `ReadLog` return type from `Log` to `List`.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> doesn't work in this case.
How can I refactor return type?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Also, you can just press F2 rather than Ctrl+R+R

Comment: You can't use rename to change `Log` to `List<Log>`. This kind of change changes the Type and also the method signature in a way that the rename feature in Visual Studio protects against. If you really need to, you can do a replace by doing `Ctrl+H` and make sure you enable all the proper toggles (match case, whole word) and select `Entire Solution`

Comment: You'd still have to modify the return variable manually on each implementations. Best to use find and replace then visit each because you'd still end up with build errors.

Comment: `Log` is a type - you can't just rename it to a different type (i.e. a `List<Log>`). If you change the signature in this way, it's a breaking change, and you will have to update all classes that implement the interface (so that they return a `List<Log>`), as well as all consumers that expect the method to return a `Log`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use rename feature to change `Log` to `List<Log>`.

This kind of change changes the type and also the method signature in a way that the rename feature in Visual Studio protects against.

If you really need to, you can do a replace by doing `Ctrl+H` (Quick Replace) or `Edit --> Find and Replace --> (pick one)` and make sure you enable all the proper toggles (match case, whole word) and select `Entire Solution`.

> As noted in the comments, this would really introduce some problems
>   and it might not be a good approach for every situation, so use it
>   with caution.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio itself only let‘s you refactor the parameters but unfortunately not the return type.

ReSharper offers this functionality with `Ctrl+R, S` https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Change_Signature.html

I don‘t know of a free extension that does this.